# Compilation of cuda samples 'opensuse 13.1'

Tags: cuda, opensuse

I have an installed cuda toolkit 6.5 on my opensuse 13.1, and have a problem with compiling cuda sample.

The output after make command is:

~# make

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/0_Simple/simpleStreams
/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64     -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o simpleStreams.o -c simpleStreams.cu
nvcc warning : The 'compute_11', 'compute_12', 'compute_13', 'sm_11', 'sm_12', and 'sm_13' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
g++: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [simpleStreams.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/0_Simple/simpleStreams
make: *** [0_Simple/simpleStreams/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Versions of my nvcc and gcc are:

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12

gcc version 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388] (SUSE Linux)

Can some one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nvcc` doesn't like `compute_1X` flags where `X` is `1,2,3`. Simply remove this: `-gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11`
code from the Makefile and you should compile correctly. Although this is just a warning is recommendable to fix all warnings to avoid trouble. Depending on `nvcc` configuration it may fail also when a warning occurs.

The problem probably arises due to the fact it does not find `g++` compiler. It may happen that you haven't installed `gcc` compiler for `c++` which is the most probable cause. Or it may happen that you have installed it manually and is not on the PATH which is the less probable cause.

To install `gcc` compiler for `c++` follow this [link](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/388834-install-g). If it doesn't work the problem is not computer related.